# Change keyboard shortcuts for for next and previous tab on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, terminal.app

I am on Mac OS X and when I used Bash (the default shell) before, to change tabs in the terminal I used <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>. Now I switched to to zsh and I have to do <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>.

How do I change these bindings?

I found out it happened because I change the language used on my computer from French to English but I don't know how to change the binding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the default shortcuts under *Window » Select Next Tab* or *Select Previous Tab*. These have nothing to do with Bash or zsh – the shortcuts work for the terminal emulator, in your case Terminal.app.

[image]

To change them, go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*. Here, add a new application shortcut:

[image]

Repeat the same for *Select Previous Tab* and the defaults will be overridden:

[image]